# how to keep only one tab or page for every user in the browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, chat, real-time

I'm writting a real-time chat application.
And I want to keep only one tab in the browser(chrome)

(firefox seems to act like that).

I've tried using cookie..

below is the js code using jquery.cookie.js

```
if($.cookie("online")){
    window.close();
}else{
    $.cookie("online",1);
}
```

But I did't get what I want.After refreshing the page will terminate the tab anyway.
and the cookie will stay alive until the browser is closed but not the tab.
Can anybody help me?

Comment: Not really answering your question, but `window.close()` only works for windows opened with `window.open()`, you cannot close arbitrary windows.

Comment: @lanzz thanks for your reply :) actually I use "window.open('', '_self', ''); window.close();" to do that..

Answer (score 1):

You cannot programaticaly close the current tab unless you opened it with Javascript.

This would also be very confusing for visitors, as they would get no information as to what happened, the window would simply close on them when they tried to open it.

Instead, consider displaying an error message or splash page telling them why they are not getting a second copy of the chat room, and telling them to return to the previous window. This would be much more user friendly.

Comment: is it possible to navigate to the previous tab?closing the tab directly is indeed not a good way...

Comment: `history.back()` will navigate to the previous page, if that helps?